# why python 3 smtplib get stuck suddenly?

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib

I'm using smtplib to send emails continuously and it works fine until it get stuck and the program just wait forever.
using latest Python 3.8 on Windows 10.
here is the code:

```
import smtplib
#import time
import datetime 

sender = 'from@abc.com'
recipient = 'to@abc.com'
user = 'from@abc.com'
password = 'password'


while True:
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    try:
        mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587, timeout=5)
        #mailserver.ehlo()
        mailserver.set_debuglevel(0)
        mailserver.starttls()
        mailserver.login(user, password)
        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(datetime.datetime.now(), "some text")
        mailserver.sendmail(sender, recipient, message)
        mailserver.quit()
        #time.sleep(1)
    except:
        print("failure")
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do some debugging please... add a print statement between every line to see which line makes your program freeze

Comment: "to send emails continuously" that sounds a *lot* like what a naive spammer would do.  Even if your purposes are legitimate, it would be no surprise if you were being throttled by the server you are connecting to.  Generating large amounts of email at a rapid rate likely requires a suitable service agreement.